Dealing with Bad invokespecial instruction
I'm converting a large library at work from groovy to java, and encountered something odd in how inheritance is handled.
Minimum Reproduceable Example:
Before groovy->java conversion
@CompileStatic trait A { boolean isValid() { return true; }}
@CompileStatic trait APrime extends A { boolean isValid() { return false; }}
@CompileStatic class UseA implements A {}
@CompileStatic class UseAPrime extends UseA implements APrime { void func() { isValid(); }}

All of that worked and behaved as expected, calls to isValid in UseAPrime.groovy returned false, and calls to isValid in UseA.groovy returned true. After converting A.groovy to A.java, this is the updated four files:
interface A { default boolean isValid() { return true; }}
@CompileStatic trait APrime implements A { boolean isValid() { return false; }}
@CompileStatic class UseA implements A {}
@CompileStatic class UseAPrime extends UseA implements APrime { void func() { isValid(); }}

The error I get at runtime is:
Caused by: java.lang.VerifyError: Bad invokespecial instruction: interface method reference is in an indirect superinterface.
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/UsesAPrime.APrimetrait$super$isValid @43: invokespecial
  Reason:
    Error exists in the bytecode
  Bytecode:
    0x0000000: 2ac1 0071 9900 252a 1271 b800 75c0 0071
    0x0000010: b900 7901 0012 7a04 bd00 4759 032b 53b8
    0x0000020: 0080 b800 6eac 0000 bf2a 2bb7 0084 ac00
    0x0000030: 0000 0000 0000 00bf                    
  Stackmap Table:
    full_frame(@38,{},{Object[#65]})
    append_frame(@41,Object[#2],Object[#135])
    full_frame(@47,{},{Object[#65]})

    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run$$$capture(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) ~[?:1.8.0_402]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750) ~[?:1.8.0_402]

The error must be a conflict caused by calling isValid in an environment where it has conflicting definitions, and the most obvious solution is to disentangle the inheritance here, probably converting all four files to java in the process, but my work environment ties my hands and requires I make incremental changes, and the web of inheritance is much much wider than the minimum example. Are there other approaches that would be effective?

How are you using trait in java? Why are you using Java 8? You know converting from groovy to java isn't just adding semicolons, yeah?

Trait is not being used in java. I'm using java 8 because that's what the codebase is written in, I have a separate effort to upgrade past java 8 that's not relevant here. I do know that converting from groovy to java is more than adding semicolons.

Seems like @CompileStatic trait APrime is going to be a problem in Java.  Maybe it's a typo in SA, but if not you probably should change that to class APrime implements A.  I'd also think removing UseA and just give UseAPrime and instance variable of APrime, and simply delegate through to it.

Java just doesn't have traits, and interfaces with default methods may seem similar, but work differently. You'll need a different architecture, this is not a 1:1 translation task.

This question is similar to: Groovy traits in java classes. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you need an intermediate step, the second answer of the linked question is probably as close as you get - keep a groovy proxy class for each java class that needs to use a trait... (doesn't work if you need multiple traits, though)

@E.D. When you said "I'm converting a large library at work from groovy to java..." that made it sound like the whole library was being converted to Java (ie no more groovy).  It wasn't clear from your question you only meant interface A was going to be in Java.

The third sentence reads "After converting A.groovy to A.java, this is the updated four files:". I suppose it needs an edit to move that up.
